# How to pass a model from a PartialView to a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a PaartialView declared like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<mvc1.Models.ProjectDetailModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm())         
<form method="get" action="EditProject" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<br />
<fieldset>
    <legend>Project Detail</legend>   
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <th class="thdetail">
            Project Code
        </th>
        <td class="tddetail">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.projectCode)
        </td>
        <tr>
        <th class="thdetail">
                Project Name
        </th>
        <td class="tddetail">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.projectName)
        </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="thdetail">
                Project Type
            </th>
            <td class="tddetail">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.projectType)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="thdetail">
                Detailed Description
            </th>
            <td class="tddetail">
            <div style="height: 100px; width:700px; overflow: scroll">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.projectDescription)
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>    
<input type="submit" value="Edit" /> 
</form>
}
```

On the submit button, i am calling a controller, but when it goes to the controller the model is not being passed back to the controller. How can i get the model back to the controller, or even just 1 field, ie. Model.projectCode which is the primary key

In the controller i have the fll which takes in the model and gets the primary key and calls a stored procedure to return results to another VIEW()

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditProject(ProjectDetailModel model)
    {
        DBController dbcontroller = new DBController();

        string l_user_name = SessionBag.Current.UserName;
        Int64 l_project_code = model.projectCode;

        if (dbcontroller.DBConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("edit_projects",   dbcontroller.conn);
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Input parameters for the insert_projects STORED PROC
            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("userName",  SessionBag.Current.UserName));
            command.Parameters["@userName"].Direction =   System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            // Output parameters for the view_sr_projects_detail STORED PROC               
            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("projectName", MySqlDbType.LongText));
            command.Parameters["@projectName"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("projectType", MySqlDbType.LongText));
            command.Parameters["@projectType"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("projectDescription", MySqlDbType.LongText));
            command.Parameters["@projectDescription"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
           try
            {
                MySqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

                var model1 = new ProjectDetailModel();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    model1.projectCode = (Int64)(rdr["projectCode"]);
                    model1.projectName = rdr["projectName"].ToString();
                    model1.projectType = rdr["projectType"].ToString();
                    model1.projectDescription = rdr["projectDescription"].ToString();
                }

                dbcontroller.conn.Close();

                return View(model1);
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                dbcontroller.conn.Close();

                ViewBag.Message = "Could not view your detail project. Error " + ex.Number + " has ocurred. Please try again or contact the system administrator.";
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Could not connect to the database. Please try again or contact the system administrator";
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class ProjectDetailModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Project Code")]
    public Int64 projectCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string srUserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
    public string projectName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Type")]
    public string projectType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Requirement")]
    public string projectDescription { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectDetailModelList : List<ProjectDetailModel>
{
}
```

thanks
Naren

Comment: Can you show the code of your controller please?

Comment: public ActionResult EditProject(ProjectDetailModel model)
        {
            DBController dbcontroller = new DBController();

            string l_user_name = SessionBag.Current.UserName;
            Int64 l_project_code = model.projectCode;

            if (dbcontroller.DBConnection())
            {
                MySqlCommand command = newMySqlCommand "edit_projects", dbcontroller.conn);

Comment: Put this code in your question so that it is more easy to read.  Also show some more code in your view.

Comment: The structure of the view model is also relevant to the question.

Comment: I copied your code from the comment to the question, but your controller code in the comment is incomplete as pasted.

Comment: If it's not a cut/paste error, you have your closing fieldset tag and form tag inside the loop in your view.  They should be outside.

Comment: Just something else that I noted, not related to question is that you have no table tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this is what you can do.  Below is just partial code, modify it to fit in with your example:

Code in your view:

```
<button id="btnEdit" type="button">Edit</button>
```

I then use `jQuery` to add a click listener to the button (make sure that jQuery is added to the view):

```
<script>

     $(document).ready(function () {

          $('#btnEdit').click(function () {
               window.location = '@Url.RouteUrl(new { action = "EditProject", projectCode = Model.projectCode })';
          });

     });

</script>
```

Your action method:

```
public ActionResult EditProject(int projectCode)
{
     // Retrieve this specific project using this code
     // Do what needs to be done to populate the required input fields on view
}
```

This is the best way that I have found to do it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback. I have tried it, but having problems with the JQuery part: projectCode = Model.projectCode })'; What i have also done, to try and get around this, i have added the fll: @{ Int64 l_pCode = item.projectCode; }, thinking i can place it into a variable and then access this variable in the Jquery using: projectCode = l_pCode .. but that doesnt work. How can i fo this ? thanks naren

Comment: Hi, Its working :-) .. I have just added this inside the foreach loop, in the above code and used it like this: '@Url.RouteUrl(new { action = "EditProject", projectCode = item.projectCode })'; Thanks alot, naren

Comment: Hi Brendan, I seem to be having format issues when coming out from the PartialView(). Does the above solution, change any formatting? Reason being, the PartialView sends a field to the controller which then calls a VIEW(). The VIEW() now doesnt really take on the attributes anymore from my style sheet. Well it does but it come out different to the other Views(). Any ideas on this ? thanks

Comment: Not sure why.  This is another question as your main question was answered and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

When MVC calls your `controller.EditProject(ProjectDetailModel)` action the binding system tries to create a `ProjectDetailModel` object from the data posted to the page (or in the query string or route data, etc.). In order for it to create and populate a `ProjectDetailModel` for you, you must have the following:

1. A parameterless constructor on `ProjectDetailModel`
2. A publically-settable property with a matching value in the form data

So if `ProjectDetailModel` looks like this:

```
public class ProjectDetailModel
{
    public ProjectDetailModel()
    {
    }

    public int ProjectId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

...you can have it populated by MVC by posting this form:

```
<form method="get" action="EditProject" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="ProjectId" name="ProjectId" value="123" />
</form>
```

**Edit**

Looking at the extra code you've added to the question, you have a few things to sort out:

1. `@using (this.Html.BeginForm())` will render an open form tag - as you've manually written one you don't need that line.
2. Using `this.Html.DisplayFor()` will just write the property value to the screen; if you want it to be populated into a parameter in your action, you need to provide the values to the binding system. You can do this by using `EditorFor()` instead of `DisplayFor()`, which will cause them to be included in the request as it is sent to the action.

Comment: My model looks like :  public class ProjectDetailModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Project Code")]
        public Int64 projectCode { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        public string srUserName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
        public string projectName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Project Type")]
        public string projectType { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Project Requirement")]
        public string projectDescription { get; set; }     public class ProjectDetailModelList : List<ProjectDetailModel>
    {}

Comment: Please don't paste code, it's difficult to read, put all code in your question.  Are you able to read this code?